# What is #_currentArena? (Syntax)

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax

I found this code in arena.dart in the ffi examples of flutter:

```
/// The last [Arena] in the zone.
factory Arena.current() {
  return Zone.current[#_currentArena];
}
```

I am puzzled and could not find anything about the `#_currentArena` thing. What type of language construct is that, and how does it work? Trying to name anything (else) starting with `#` gives immediate errors; auto completion doesn't find it, and trying to go to its definition doesn't work either.

So this seems to be something extremely special, and extremely undocumented... leaving me extremely curious!

[Link to source file in Flutter SDK Sqlite Example](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/samples/ffi/sqlite/lib/src/ffi/arena.dart)

Comment: what "ffi examples" do you mean? I have `arena.dart` only in `lib/src/gestures` folder

Comment: @pskink I've included the link to the source file.

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#symbols, i never used it though...

Comment: Thank you, the Symbol thing was new to me, it seems rarely needed in everyday use.

Comment: yeah, they seem to be black voodoo magic ... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @pskink pointed out in his comment, this is part of the [symbols](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#symbols).

> A Symbol object represents an operator or identifier declared in a
> Dart program. You might never need to use symbols, but they’re
> invaluable for APIs that refer to identifiers by name, because
> minification changes identifier names but not identifier symbols.
>
> To get the symbol for an identifier, use a symbol literal, which is
> just # followed by the identifier:
>
> ```
> #radix
> #bar
> ```
>
> Symbol literals are compile-time constants.